# Difference between `do.call()` a function and directly call a function in R?

Tags: r, do.call

Here is my code:

```
>ipo_num_year<- do.call(length,list(as.name(paste0("all_data_align_",year))))
>ipo_num_year
>90
>ipo_num_year<- length(as.name(paste0("all_data_align_",year)))
>ipo_num_year
>1
```

`year` is an string object "1999";

In previous code,`all_data_align_1999` has been assigned as an list with `90` elements,so the right result is `ipo_num_year` equals to `90`.But the second line makes `ipo_num_year` equals to `1`,it means `length()` function look the return value of `as.name()` as an `symbol` object,so its length is just `1`.

Why does the return value of `as.name()` can not be directly used as the argument of function `length()`?
And why the first solution works fine?

Some one may ask that why don't you just use `length(all_data_align_1999)`.That is because the `year` is an loop variable in my code.

Really appreciate your kindly reply!

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of `all_data_align_*` variables in your workspace? Put them all in a list and everything will be easier.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Roland .I was just ready to do as what you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `as.name` you should use `get`:

```
length(get(paste0("all_data_align_",year)))
```

You need to retrieve the object not just the name.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,Is that because list() will retrieve the object when it try to take it as its element in the first solution ?

Comment: The `do.call` function evaluates the argument, so it uses a kind of `get` function for each of the element of the list, so replaces the name with its value before calling the `length` function. To avoid, evaluation, you should use the `quote = TRUE` argument